# How to do subclass reflection in trait of scala

Tags: scala

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

trait someTrait{
  def getType[T: ru.TypeTag](obj: T) = ru.typeOf[T]
  def reflect()={
       println(getType(this))  // got someTrait type, not A type.
    }
}

class A extends someTrait{

}

main(){
   new A().reflect()
}
```

When I run main function, I got **someTrait** type printed out.
How can I get **A** type in **reflect** function?

Comment: Why exactly do you need this? Maybe a simple `this.getClass` would work?

Comment: I want to do reflection, then invoke some functions of subclass.

Comment: That sounds like `getClass` might do it. But it also sounds like a design issue. Maybe there is a way to avoid reflection.

Comment: I want to invoke all function with special parameters. As the scala document says, we cant use java reflectoin since it might cause problem.

Answer (score 2):

Using `TypeTag`s or `ClassTag`s, you can't (without doing extra work in every subtype, as Ramesh's answer does). Because the compiler inserts them based on static types only.

When it sees `getType(this)`, it first infers type parameter to `getType[someTrait](this)`, and then turns into `getType[someTrait](this)(typeTag[someTrait])`. You can see `A` is never considered *and it can't be*.

> As the scala document says, we cant use java reflectoin since it might cause problem.

No, Scala documentation certainly doesn't say you can't use Java reflection *for this*. You need to understand its limitations but exactly the same applies to Scala reflection.